# How can I redirect from one Next.js app with basePath set to another in an Nx monorepo setup?

Tags: next.js, next.js13, nomachine-nx, nextjs-redirects

I have an Nx monorepo setup with multiple Next.js apps. Each Next.js app has its `basePath` set to `'/apps/appName'` e.g. Users app's `basePath` is `/apps/users`. There's a root app that lists the applications and has no `basePath` set in order to run at `/` and one of its routes is `/login`. I am using `redirect` from `next/navigation` in the Users app to redirect to the root app's `/login` by writing `redirect('/login');` but I redirect to `/apps/users/login` instead. The only way to achieve the desired result is by writing `redirect('../../login');`. Has anyone faced a similar problem before? I'm not liking the relative path passed in `redirect`.